# .. Oprator in Dart for python

Tags: python

there is `..` operator in Dart it is a shortcut where we can apply some function on the object and after applying it returns the same object back.

example:-

this code:

`obj = Object()
 obj.apply()`

could be written as:

`obj = Object()..apply()`

in one line.

Is there any way to do this in python?

Comment: Not really. You can probably bend over backwards in various ways to do it, but that will end up more complicated than the simple two-line version. And that's probably on purpose, as Python's mantra puts emphasis on readability.

Answer (score -1):

you can define a wraper function:

```
class Foo:

    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 100

    def bar(self):
        # Do something to change the obect, e.g.:
        self.x += 10

    def _wraper(self, function, *args, **kwargs):
        self.__getattribute__(function.__name__)(*args, **kwargs)
        return self

foo = Foo()._wraper(Foo.bar)
print(foo.x)  # Will print 110
```